# How to prevent alpine.js modal from showing every time i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

i'm using alpine.js for my project and I have a modal that works well with alpine.js, my problem is that whenever you refresh the page, it shows for a second or two (while the page loads) and then goes away. I don't want to see it onload. Is there any way to workaround that in alpine.js?

My code

```
// Initialize data
<body x-data="{openModal: false}"
 :class="openModal ? 'overflow-hidden' : 'overflow-visible'"
>

// button
<button @click="openModal = true">
Open Modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div x-show="openModal">
<!-- content --> 
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for the `x-cloak` directive.

It's a very simple one, it gets removed from the component when Alpine starts up.

So in your case you can add the following `style` (which will hide elements with the `x-cloak` attribute) and add `x-cloak` to your Alpine.js component (in this case the `body`).

```html
<style>
[x-cloak] { display: none }
</style>
<body x-cloak x-data="{openModal: false}"
 :class="openModal ? 'overflow-hidden' : 'overflow-visible'"
>

// button
<button @click="openModal = true">
Open Modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div x-show="openModal">
<!-- content --> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. In my head i have my css, my alpine.js script tag and underneath I put your suggestion.

Comment: Nvm i got it, didn't notice that you added x-cloak to body, my bad.

Comment: Yep, maybe I'll update the answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 10):

**x-cloak** is the right answear! But to be on the safe side in more cases, use the css important rule.

```
<style>
  [x-cloak] { 
      display: none !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: that's works... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `x-clock` solution, another solution is to wrap the content you want to control in a `<template>` tag with an `x-if="true"` parameter.
Check the code below.

```
<template x-if="true">
  <div x-show="openModal">
    <!-- content --> 
  </div>
</template>
```

This works because `<template>` elements are "hidden" in browsers by default, you won't see the `<div>` until Alpine has had a chance to render the `x-if="true"` and show it as the docs describe [here](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/cloak)

Answer (score 0):

In my laravel project I added this code into resources/css/app.css

```
  [x-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
   }
```

Then in my div with Alpine.js asigned x-cloack property:

```
<div x-data="{ showModal: false }" x-cloak>
</div>
```

It  works! Thanks